# Using C++ dll object within C#

Tags: c#, c++, mono

I have a third party C++ .dll which exports some classes which I wish to use from C#. The dll is a Win32 application and I'm working on Windows 8.1 using VS2013. When I set up the C# program running under 'Any CPU', I get the error "System.BadImageFormatException". I've read other places that this can be caused by combining x86 and x64. So I recompiled the C# program as x86. Now I get "Unable to load DLL 'libsword.dll': The specified module could not be found". I've made sure the dll is in the proper directory.

All of this works just fine on Linux using Mono.

At this point, I've got no idea how to proceed.

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the C++ library, which was originally written and developed for Linux. Export was defined as:

```
define SWDLLEXPORT _declspec( dllexport )
```

Which was used as:

```
const char * SWDLLEXPORT  function_name(args)
```

which worked in Linux but not in Windows. Changing the function signature to:

```
const char SWDLLEXPORT * function_name(args)
```

Works in both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

BadImageFormatException is thrown when you treat regular native C++ code in a DLL as if it was .NET code.  .NET also puts code in the .DLL files.

You'll need to create C# declarations for the C++ code, so that .NET knows how to transition from managed (.NET/C#) code to native (C++) code.  This is fairly complicated, depending on what the code in your 3rd party library looks like.  Too much for me to speculate what you need to do.

Comment: A `BadImageFormatException` doesn't come from trying to load an unmanaged assembly - instead it's a `FileLoadException`. The `BadImageFormatException` is when the bitness of the assembly doesn't match the process into which it is loaded, or if the framework doesn't understand the version it is built for.

Comment: @codekaizen, the documentation on MSDN says "You try to load an unmanaged dynamic link library or executable (such as a Windows system DLL) as if it were a .NET Framework assembly."  If we get more info from Jon, we can determine if that's the case or some other problem.

Comment: The C++ code uses dllexport on all the interface functions and the C# code uses DllImport on those functions. As I said above, it all works on Linux in MONO

Comment: The doc for that exception lists several possible causes.  Can you make a small project that reproduces the problem?  Is there more detail in the exception that would give a clue?

Comment: The project is a very small one, really just a test case, but the dll is quite large and complex. Unfortunately, there's nothing helpful in the exception. The dll which is the heart of things is a Linux project which has instructions for building in Windows. Unfortunately, it's been about 10 years since I did any serious C++ programming.

Comment: Assuming it is a native Windows DLL rather than C++ code compiled to be .NET code, the problem is probably in the DllImport, or the settings in Visual Studio.  Trying to make an educated guess based on what I've heard so far.  Sorry that I can't be definitive - not enough detail.  Generally speaking, it's possible to call native C++ from C#.

Comment: Found it. Turns out the dll was loading other dlls which it could not find. The error simply indicated that the top level dll could not load - no mention of what was actually missing.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, and posted your observations here.

Comment: Yeah, the thing that threw me off was it working in C# Mono on Linux. Turns out that the build of the .so in Linux registered all the rest of the dependencies. Not so in Windows.

Comment: Use something like dll dependency walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/.) if you are working with .dlls a lot. Heleped me out a lot. It can report any missing dependent dlls.